# Patchwork Filesystem path doesn't works

Tags: python, input

I recently created a program including commands like help, that make the program read a text file named help.tosext using the arg open("file path", "r"). I proceeded like that for other commands displaying other text files. Then I tried to shorten this mess by creating a input value with the program files path, as following :

```
filesyspath = input("Please specify the program location's path :")
```

In order to be able to do something like

```
open(filesyspath,"/tosext", "r")
```

(/tosext is the location of all the text files that I d'like to display in my program)

In other words, I tried to make an input with the adress of the program's location, and to put it at the beginning of a function needing some .tosext files)

But when I tried to invoke the help text file, it said me

`Type <help> to get a list of available commands.
Please specify the filesystem's location path :/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/TemOS
-->help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/TemOS/.last_tmp.py", line 59, in <module>
    hlp = open(syspath,"/tosext/help.tosext", "r")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`

I know where the errors comes from (the programs expects an integer) but I don't know other solutions to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`syspath` and `"/tosext/help.tosext"` must be joined together to form the path:

```
hlp = open(syspath + "/tosext/help.tosext", "r")
```

The first parameter of `open` is the path (a string), the second is the mode (another string), and the third is buffering (an integer). Normally, you do not want to use the third parameter.

Comment: Preferably use `os.path.join(syspath, "tosext", "help.tosext")` instead of `+`-ing the components.